# Gantt chart in direct query mode || Data format (dd/mm/yyyy) mismatch on hover over in chart

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I have created a gantt chart in direct query mode, data in the database is in the format of dd/mm/yyyy, but while hovering tasks in chart I see 12:00:00 AM in both start and end date.
May I know how to get it resolved?

I used DAX query, tool tip button and used measures but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the format in tooltip settings of the visual.

Comment: it worked, Thank you Chandna sai